# Azure sign in using Organisation ID (from Synchronized Azure AD)

Tags: azure, authentication, subscription

I have an issue logging into Azure using my synchronized Organisation ID's which have been synchronized from my local AD to Azure AD.

To date, using a user@onmicrosoft.com account I have:

1. created an Office 365 Trial, and received an associated Azure trial.
2. configured Office 365 and Azure with my companies domain.
3. configured Azure AD for Directory Synchronization with my local AD and Single Sign On, all of which is working perfectly.

I am able to now login to Office 365 using my Organisation ID, and leverage single sign in.

Problem is, I cannot login to Azure Management Portal using my (or any) Organisation ID, as I get "No subscriptions found"

I have configured my Organisation ID user (synced from local AD), in Azure AD to be a Global Administrator.

There seems to be some step I'm missing to associate my newly synchronized AD accounts to Azure, so I can use them to actually administer Azure.

In reading up online, when creating the Azure Active Directory there is an option to add co-administrators, but there seems to be now way to do this after the fact, (my Azure AD was there already when i created the office 365 trial).

Can someone point me in the right direction so I can use Synced Organization IDs to login to Azure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Global Administrator account in a Azure AD is Administrator only for the Directory itself, not for the Azure subscription. In order to make any of your synchronized accounts also Subscription administrators you have two options:

1. Using current portal (https://manage.windowsazure.com/)

   1.Login with the account that you used to create the subscription

   2. Navigate to "Settings" on the left menu (most bottom item)
   3. Chose the "Administrators" tab
   4. Click on the ADD buttom on the bottom bar:
      [image]
   5. Next enter the fully qualified login of the synchronized user (e-mail address)
   6. User shall be recognized by the system
   7. Confirm:
      [image]
2. Using the new portal and the whole new RBAC goodies (Role-Based-Access-Control) - https://portal.azure.com/
3. login to the portal with the account that you created the subscription
4. Click on the "Browse" button from the left bar
5. Select "Subscriptions" element
6. Click on the subscription:
   [image]
7. Once on the subscription blade, click on "Users"
8. Then click on the "+Add" button on top of the "users" blade:
   [image]
9. Next is super intuitive interface which will even list all the users. You have to first a role for the user, then chose users or just Groups (that are also synced from your AD).

Comment: Brilliant - Thanks astaykov. That's exactly what I was after and worked perfectly. 2 answers for the price of one even!